# マルチサイト化した複数のwordpressサイトを、アクセス元の国によって切り替えて表示する方法を知りたい

Tags: apache, wordpress

マルチサイト化したwordpressサイトを表示させる方法を知りたいです。

例えば、同じサーバーの中にマルチサイトを利用して、2つのwordpressサイトを作ります。

- A：sample.com
- B：sample.com/en

最初のアクセスに利用するドメインは、Aのsample.comのみで、

- 日本からのアクセスの場合→A：sample.com
- 海外からのアクセスの場合（またはブラウザの検索条件を日本語以外にしている場合）→B：sample.com/en

というように、1つのURLのみの使用で、アクセス元やブラウザーの条件によって、A、Bへアクセスが変わるようにしたいのですが、

- このような方法は可能でしょうか？
- また、可能な場合どのような方法で対応できるでしょうか？

ご存じの方おりましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

◆環境
CentOS (7 x86_64)
Apache (2.4.6 CentOS)
PHP (7.1.33)
wordpress(5.2.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いくつかの方法が考えられますが、例えば GeoIP などのIPアドレスを元に判別する場合でも、**アクセス元の国** と **利用者が理解できる言語** とが必ずしも一致しないケースを考慮する必要があります。
(旅行や出張で海外にいる、VPNを利用している etc..)

現実的には環境変数 `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` からブラウザの優先言語を取得して、webページ側で振り分けるのがよさそうです。

例えば PHP であれば、以下のようなコードでブラウザの優先言語を取得できるようです。

**参考:**
[PHP: Locale::acceptFromHttp - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/locale.acceptfromhttp.php)

**サンプルコード**

```php
<?php
$locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
echo $locale;
?>
```

**結果:**

```
en_US, ja_JP など
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGEをキーワードに検索すると、参考になるサイトをいくつが見つける事ができますので、それらも活用して対応したいと思います。